# Estoy creando un Theme de Wordpress y no se aplican los estilos los widgets. Donde esta el problema?

Tags: php, css3, wordpress

Voy a dejar las partes del código concretas que se refieren a esta pregunta, pero si alguien necesita que le muestre más cosas, no hay problema.
El sidebar y los widgets se ven perfectamente, pero no se aplican los estilos en los widgets.

Este es el codigo de archivo functions.php

```
 if(!function_exists('fwpt_register_sidebars')):    
    function fwpt_register_sidebars(){

    register_sidebar (array(
        'name' =>__('Sidebar Principal','fwpt'),  
        'id' =>'main_sidebar',
        'description' =>__('Este es el sidebar principal','fwpt'),
        'before_widget'=>'<article id="%1$s" class="Widget%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</article>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));

    register_sidebar (array(
        'name' =>__('Sidebar Pié de Página','fwpt'),
        'id' =>'footer_sidebar',
        'description' =>__('Este es el sidebar del pié de página','fwpt'),
        'before_widget'=>'<article id="%1$s" class="Widget%2$s">',
        'after_widget' => '</article>',
        'before_title' => '<h3>',
        'after_title' => '</h3>'
    ));
    }

endif;
```

Aquí la plantilla del sidebar

```
<aside class="Sidebar">
    
    <?php 
    if (is_active_sidebar('main_sidebar')):
    dynamic_sidebar('main_sidebar');
    else:
    ?>
    <article class="Widget">
        <h3><?php _e('Buscar','fwpt');?></h3>
        <?php get_search_form();?>
    </article>
    <?php endif;?> 

</aside>
```

Y los estilos

```
.Sidebar {
    grid-area: sidebar;
}

.Other {
    grid-area: other;
}

.Widget,
.Pagination{
    background-color: #AAA;
    margin-bottom:2rem;
    padding:1rem;
}
```

Tengo que decir que .Pagination si que aplica los estilos, pero .Widget no.
Gracias por vuestra ayuda

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El problema es en esta linea  
`'before_widget'=>'<article id="%1$s" class="Widget%2$s">',` le estas pasando el nombre del widget en la clase, por lo que te estaría generado algo como `class="WidgetNombreDelWidget"` en el fronted, intenta agregando un espacio en el WidgetClass así 
`'before_widget'=>'<article id="%1$s" class="Widget %2$s">',` para que te genere algo como esto `class="Widget NombreDelWidget"`